# how get multi options from multi selectbox in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, drop-down-menu, nuxt.js

I have many select boxes that have many options and are dynamic.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <tr v-for="category in categories.items" :key="category.id">
      <td>
        <select v-model.trim="$v.form.attributeValues.$model" class="form-control">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option v-for="option in category.values" :key="option.id" :value="option">
            {{ option.content }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      categories: null,
      form: {
        productId: this.product.productId,
        attributeValues: [],
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I want get the values of theme and save it in an array.
But it doesn't work and I can only save 1 option.

like this:
(get just one option from each selectbox)
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand the image here. Can you please link a website where you see the same kind of input?

Answer (score 1):

A multi-select is far from being a trivial a trivial component.

Most people simply use [vue-multiselect](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect) or any [package alike](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#select).
There is also a ton available only. You should look for the one matching your wanted features.

If you want to implement it manually, you will need to deal with binding the proper inputs, events and structure since it is not achievable with a simple `v-model`.
One of the best article on this is [this one](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/building-custom-multi-option-form-components-with-vue/).

Still, it all depends on how you want it to look like, the behavior of the various options, the way to select it (keyboard, ctrl + click, simple click etc...), the transitions etc...

TLDR: use a package or try it yourself and show us what you achieved so far if you want some debugging.
The community will not write a complex component from scratch for you tho.

Comment: tnx but i want create multi-select i want create multi-selectbox like this picture that i add in my question

Comment: @faezeh not sure what is a "multi-selectbox".

Comment: like picture that i add in my questio now.
it means more than one selectbox 
i have many selectbox that are dynamic and comes from server

Comment: @faezeh as told, I don't really understand the linked image. Also, please focus on some (mocked) static data, then you'll see how to handle this dynamically. Don't rush things.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `v-model` and a `input-event` to your option like this:

*template*

```html
<option v-model="selectedItem" @input="checkItem(selectedItem)">
  <!-- Your code -->
</option>
```

Than go to your script and define everything. After that you can make a method called `checkItem` and there you will `push` everything in a defined `array` which you have selected.

*script*

```js
data() {
  return {
    selectedItem: null,
    allItems: [],
  }
},

methods: {
  checkItem(selectedItem) {
    this.allItems.push(selectedItem)
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps you out - pls let me know!

Comment: How do you uncheck in your example?

Comment: Also, what's the point of keeping `v-model` any longer if you use an input event? Btw, are you sure `@input` is working on an option, it's not a keyboard input even listener AFAIK. Also, if you're giving an example, please also link the caveats when working with [an array/object](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) because OP will face those pretty quickly if she tries to make a homemade solution.

Comment: @BOBBY I have this error from eslint :
'v-model' directives aren't supported on <option> elements.eslint-plugin-vue

Comment: @faezeh you got your answer here already. You will need some custom events here, as you can guess (and as I told you already), your example is not trivial (hence `v-model` will not be enough in your case).

Comment: @kissu  yes but `@input` is not work on options and i want get both of selectbox name an option names